# Wordpress - Page and custom post type with this same slug

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, slug

I have custom post type with "events" slug and page with this same slug ('/events').
When I use this same slug for page and CPT then I have 404 error - pagination.
I changed "with_front" to true/false but this not work.
I do not know what is wrong.

My code:

```
function mr_cpt_event() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Event', 'Post Type General Name', 'mr' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Event', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'mr' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Events', 'mr' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Event Type', 'mr' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Event Archives', 'mr' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Event', 'mr' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Events', 'mr' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Event', 'mr' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'mr' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Event', 'mr' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Event', 'mr' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Event', 'mr' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Event', 'mr' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Event', 'mr' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'mr' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'mr' ),
        'featurmr_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'mr' ),
        'set_featurmr_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'mr' ),
        'remove_featurmr_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'mr' ),
        'use_featurmr_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'mr' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'mr' ),
        'uploadmr_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'mr' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'mr' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'mr' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'mr' )
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                  => 'events',
        'with_front'            => false,
        'pages'                 => true,
        'feeds'                 => true
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Event', 'mr' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Events', 'mr' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'event_category', 'event_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-laptop',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'       => 'post'
    );
    register_post_type( 'event', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'mr_cpt_event', 0 );
```

Comment: You cannot have a page and post type with same slug. You will have to change one of them to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have the same slug or name for page and post type. 
so either you have to disable the archive page of the post by using this:

```
register_post_type( 'events',
array(
    [...]
    'has_archive' => false,
    [...]
)
```

);

OR you have to change either the post name/slug or page name/slug

Comment: Thanks, but I have "has_archive => false". I have page with "/events" slug.
I need page with slug "/events" and single event page "/events/my-event".

Comment: Then you have to change anyone's slug post slug and page slug can't be same they will conflict with each other..  You can change the post slug to event insted of events